# How to export a password-protected private key using MS CryptoAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, cryptoapi

Using Microsoft CryptoAPI, I've generated a new RSA key pair, and am now trying to export the private key to a PKCS#8 encrypted (password-protected) PEM file.

I first investigated CryptExportPKCS8() and CryptExportPKCS8Ex(), but the former doesn't support encrypting the key, and the latter is [not exported by crypt32.dll](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.security.narkive.com/7sfErwMZ/where-is-cryptexportpkcs8ex#post5). MSDN says that both functions have been deprecated anyway.

My current attempt is to pass a session key derived from the password to CryptExportKey():

```
HCRYPTPROV provider;
BOOL result = CryptAcquireContext(&provider, CONTAINER_NAME, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET | CRYPT_SILENT);
HCRYPTKEY keyPair;
result = CryptGenKey(provider, CALG_RSA_KEYX, (2048 << 16) | CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &keyPair);

HCRYPTHASH hash;
result = CryptCreateHash(provider, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hash);
const char *password = "password";
result = CryptHashData(hash, (const BYTE *)password, strlen(password), 0);
HCRYPTKEY sessionKey;
result = CryptDeriveKey(provider, CALG_3DES, hash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &sessionKey);

DWORD blobSize;
result = CryptExportKey(keyPair, sessionKey, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, NULL, &blobSize);
BYTE *blobBytes = new BYTE[blobSize];
result = CryptExportKey(keyPair, sessionKey, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, blobBytes, &blobSize);

DWORD derSize;
// This throws "First-chance exception ... Access violation reading ..." and returns FALSE
result = CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, blobBytes, 0, NULL, NULL, &derSize);
// error is 3221225477 (0xC0000005)
DWORD error = GetLastError();
BYTE *derBytes = new BYTE[derSize];
result = CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, blobBytes, 0, NULL, derBytes, &derSize);

// ... CryptBinaryToString() to convert to PEM

// ... Write PEM to file
```

All calls succeed up until the commented CryptEncodeObjectEx().

If I don't pass the session key to CryptExportKey() then I can successfully use CryptEncodeObjectEx() to encode the private key, but obviously it is then plain-text.

How can I export a password-protected private key? Is there something wrong with the way I derive the session key? Is PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY the wrong encoding type?

I've been testing in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY used only when private key blob not encrypted. when it encrypted you must use PKCS_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO. example of working code

```
BOOL expKey(PCSTR password)
{
    BOOL fOk = FALSE;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    if (CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, 0, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        HCRYPTKEY hKey, hExpKey;
        HCRYPTHASH hHash;

        BOOL f = FALSE;

        if (CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash))
        {
            if (CryptHashData(hHash, (PBYTE)password, (ULONG)strlen(password), 0))
            {
                f = CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_3DES, hHash, 0, &hExpKey);
            }
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        }

        if (f)
        {
            if (CryptGenKey(hProv, CALG_RSA_KEYX, RSA1024BIT_KEY*2|CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey))
            {
                CRYPT_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO cepki = {{ szOID_RSA_DES_EDE3_CBC}};
                if (
                    CryptExportKey(hKey, hExpKey, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, 0, &cepki.EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData) &&
                    CryptExportKey(hKey, hExpKey, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, cepki.EncryptedPrivateKey.pbData = (PBYTE)alloca(cepki.EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData), &cepki.EncryptedPrivateKey.cbData)
                    )
                {
                    ULONG cb;
                    PVOID pvEncoded;
                    if (CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO, &cepki, CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 0, &pvEncoded, &(cb = sizeof(PVOID))))
                    {
                        fOk = TRUE;
                        LocalFree(pvEncoded);
                    }
                }
            }
            CryptDestroyKey(hExpKey);
        }
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    }

    return fOk;
}
```

Comment: What format is pvEncoded? `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in test.der` shows valid ASN.1, but `openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in test.der` gives `unknown pbe algorithm:evp_pbe.c:162:TYPE=des-ede3-cbc`.